# linux command to zip multiple files before move multiple files to other directory

Tags: unix

1) I want to zip a thousand documents into a zip file,

2) after zip complete, then move a thousand files to different directory.

How can I accomplish this. Try command below but it is not working.  Thanks

```
[documents]> zip 1000-docs.zip `ls | head -1000` | xargs -I {} mv {} /documents/completed/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zip displays " adding: filename" for every file that it adds to the archive. This isn't the format expected by mv. You can extract the filename using awk (not handling whitespace in filenames).

```
[documents]> zip 1000-docs.zip `ls | head -1000` | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} mv {} /documents/completed/
```

or sed

```
[documents]> zip 1000-docs.zip `ls | head -1000` | sed 's/.*adding: //' | xargs -I {} mv {} /documents/completed/
```